# ACTION_SEND intent-filter for all images including Picasa

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have this declared in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name="x.y.z.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

What I am trying to do is to register my activity for sharing of images from other apps. This works for normal images from the Gallery but my app doesn't appear as option for sharing of images from the Gallery that are up on Picasa. I'm not sure what else to add to my intent-filter to cover also this use case.

Comment: if you got any application that appears as handler for these images, get Root Explorer or appXPlorer an inspect their Manifest file on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Intent Intercept app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) to intercept the intent from the Gallery.

Unfortunately I see that the mime type is text/plain and there is an extra that contains the link to the image. I can't use this mime type because my app is only able to handle images and not text (the app might show up in apps that share text and obviously I don't want that).

Short answer: this cannot be done if you don't also implement sharing of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<data android:mimeType="*/*" />
```

and debug/log the type of the Intent sent by Picasa to add it to your intent filter.